# Shiny sliderInput skipping Days of the Week

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a scatterplot that is animated by date using shiny sliderInput. However I do not have data for every day of the week, and for those days the plot is just an empty gray box. Is there a way to make my sliderinput skip certain days of the week so that I do not show the blank plot for days that I do not have data? I have included an example.

```
   library(shiny)
   library(lubridate)

airqual <- airquality %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(airquality$Month, airquality$Day, 
      sep = "-"), format = "%m-%d")) %>%
   filter(wday(date) %in% c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

   animationOptions(loop = TRUE)
ui <- fluidPage(

 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("date",
              "The date",
              min = min(airqual$date),
              value = min(airqual$date),
              max = max(airqual$date),
              animate = TRUE
  )),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)
  )
)

 server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
# generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
airqual %>%
  filter(date == input$date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ozone, y = Solar.R)) +
  geom_point()
 })
}

# Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating the data according to your needs:

```
  data <- eventReactive(input$date, {
    x <- airqual %>%
      filter(date == input$date)
    if(nrow(x) == 0) {
      print(input$date)
      updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "date", value = input$date+1)
      NULL
    } else { x }
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    req(data()) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Ozone, y = Solar.R)) +
      geom_point()
  })
```

Comment: This code did not work for me as it is but seeing updateSliderInput is very helpful.

Comment: Some of the dates ploted had missing values with this code... but you'd only have to adjust the `filter` in `data` (adding something like `& !is.na(Ozone) & !is.na(Solar.R)`). Was it something else?

Comment: I think missing data shows as a plot with no dots on it, and when it is Monday the plot is just a gray square. I found that even with this code I was still getting empty gray squares.

Comment: When the date is not in the data, you get a red warning message (that's what the code is dealing with). When the data is missing in only one of the axis you get the plot with no dots, and you get the gray square when both axis are missing. Have you tried the filter I've commented?